# Spoilers as comment?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

Someone tries a puzzle, gets a little degree of success, and posts a comment or answer that is kinda spoiler. This is bad, what do you people think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In my opinion teamwork is always a great thing!**
Some puzzles are very hard to solve, sometimes impossible for a single human to discern all the elements of the puzzle.
Everyone should be able to contribute as much as he can, unless the author specifically forbids teamwork.
That's valid for any kind of puzzle, especially those involving ciphers and cryptograms.
Take this for example: 
**[Five puzzles in one!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11594/five-puzzles-in-one)**
In that puzzle, I recommended people to collaborate to solve the puzzles, and it brilliantly worked! Somebody was able to decrypt a cipher, someone else caught a hint, another one put the pieces together, and so on!
I can provide many examples where cooperation led to incredible success in hard tasks, so why not encourage it?

Comment: Cooperation is a great way to complete a task, to be sure, but the point of a puzzle is not to complete a task.  It is to entertain by misleading until the reader experiences an insight that leads to the solution.  The opportunity to experience the insight is, IMO, the primary reason for engaging in a puzzle in the first place.  But one can't experience an insight when the solution is already before one's eyes.